# How to implements onclick listview in fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to give `onClick` in my `listview` . I'm using `menu drawer` here is my `mainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment Fragment = null;

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_item:
                Fragment = new Item();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_do:
                Fragment = new Deliveryorder();
                break;
        }

        if (Fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }    
}
```

then here is one of my `fragment`

```
public class Item extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ListView listView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Menu Item");
        getJSON("http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login/fppb");
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        List<Itemadapter> items = new ArrayList<Itemadapter>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] ba = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String code     = obj.getString("ItemCode");
            String name     = obj.getString("ItemName");
            String photo    = obj.getString("PhotoName");
            items.add(new Itemadapter(code, name,photo));
        }
       //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), items.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Itemadapter>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,items);
        listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }

    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;

                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }

        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }
}
```

when i run my app and open `Item.java` the data is showing up, but when i click one row there's nothing happen. I already add this

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: You need to assign a listener with: `listView.setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a listener :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: you're welcome. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790688/5154891) posted by @FENIL PATEL is a good tutorial.

Comment: if possible, can you tell how to get the value ?

Comment: listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);

Answer (score 1):

[Hello, Please check out the following link, here you get the complete guidance about how to implement listview in fragment and how to impalement click listener on listview items.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: You need to write click listener logic inside the getViewChild() override method.

Comment: it's using `ListFragment `, when i change my `Fragment` to `ListFragment` i get this error  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.boby.firstapp/com.example.boby.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`